# express-jwt handling specific secret passphrase by routes

Tags: node.js, express, token, jwt, express-jwt

Here is my use case.

In my express app using express-jwt module, I have 2 mains routes. I would like to secure my routes with 2 distincts passphrase.

```
app.use('/api/v1/admin', jwt({secret: "blabla1"}).unless({path:['/api/v1/admin/login']}));
app.use('/api/v1', jwt({secret: "blabla2"}).unless({path: ['/api/v1/login']}));
```

In this case, it doesn't work as I was expecting to... 
Is there a way to achieve this in only one express app ?

Thanks in advance for your helps guys!

Comment: What is not working correctly, can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi, sure, in this case, I'm not able to log in as admin. I got POST /api/v1/admin/login 401
error: No authorization token was found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off, what you are doing above is setting the secret for the whole app.  If you wanted to protect a certain route you could do something like below.

```
app.all('/api/v1', jwt({secret: "blabla2"}).unless({path: ['/api/v1/login']}));
app.all('/api/v1/admin', jwt({secret: "blabla1"}).unless({path:['/api/v1/admin/login']}));
```

The above code allows you define different secrets for a particular route.  The call to `app.all` catches every type of HTTP call.