# express-jwt can't access req.user from routes directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, auth0, express-jwt

New to express...

I can access `req.user` when I handle requests inside my `app.js` file. However, routes that I define inside my routes folder (specifically `routes/users.js`) don't have `req.user` even though I authenticate them in `app.js` `(app.use('/users', authenticate);`. As I mentioned, I am new to express so I am probably configuring something incorrectly. Any tips are much appreciated! Let me know if this is unclear or you need more information. Thanks!

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var cors = require('cors');
var http = require('http');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

dotenv.load();

var authenticate = jwt({
  secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
});

app.use(cors());
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/users', authenticate);
app.use('/secured', authenticate);


app.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
  res.send("All good. You don't need to be authenticated to call this");
});


app.get('/secured/ping', function(req, res) {
  // req.user works here!
  res.status(200).send("All good. You only get this message if you're authenticated");
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

http.createServer(app).listen(port, function (err) {
  console.log('listening in http://localhost:' + port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

routes/users.js

```
var models  = require('../models');
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  // req.user = undefined
  console.log("user: " + req.user.sub)
  models.User.findOrCreate({
    where: {tokenId: req.user.sub},
    defaults: {
      name: req.body.name,
      tokenId: req.user.sub,
      points: 0
    }
  }).then(function(user) {
    res.json(JSON.stringify(user));
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: try to change the order to `app.use('/users', authenticate);app.use('/users', users);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the ordering of the following code in **app.js**

```
//some code
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/users', authenticate);
//some code
```

Nodejs works in sequential manner. So, it will read the users route in *routes/users.js* first and then authenticate function. In this way, there would undefined `req.user` as authenticate function is called afterwards.

If you try to access `req.user` after `app.use('/users', authenticate)`, it won't be undefined ( express-jwt works properly).

Now, if you change the code to

```
//some code
app.use('/users', authenticate);
app.use('/users', users);
//some code
```

then, it will authenticate the user and put the user object in `req.user` and can be accessible afterwards.

Hope it works for you. Let me know, if there is any issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... when I switch those lines I get `UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found`.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496439/express-jwt-not-respecting-unprotected-paths

Comment: Turns out my request wasn't properly setting the authorization header.  After fixing that and making this change it works!  Thanks!